# wried cakephp auth behavior

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a very small application where i have set up the Auth component.

There is one problem though

Everytime i try to access the Auth component the whole session is destoryed.

my Appcontroller looks like this

```
    class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'home', 'home')
    )
);

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');


    }
}
```

Now this does ***not*** work

however if i remove:

```
            $this->Auth->allow('*');
```

The session appears and is now there.

So my question is why is this happening?

The problem with the result is that no matter what the user is being redirected to login unless they are logged in (meaning no one can see my 'home' page)

Im using `CakePHP 2.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public.

I think you should use:

```
$this->Auth->allow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authorize' => 'controller',
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'home'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'home', 'home')
)
```

Comment: here i get Authorization adapter "controller" was not found.

Comment: 'authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')) is working?